# Run command on master before/after slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to trigger a command on master before the job runs on the slave and one after something like this:

1. Master setup
2. Slave build
3. Master teardown

I have tried to search for a while and browse all plugins but so far I didn't find anything. Is it possible ?

I found that someone was looking for the same [here](http://osdir.com/ml/java-jenkins-user/2011-05/msg00734.html) but got no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup this behavior with the [Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

Create a Flow with your 3 steps as Jenkins jobs in sequence. Restrict the machines where specific builds will be executed.

1. setup on master
2. build on slave
3. teardown on master

You can pass build parameters across builds with the Flow DSL.

Comment: I was hoping that it was possible without using different jobs, but I guess not. This seem like it should work though.